# Which verses of Brahma Sutras state that devas do not have gross bodies?

Tags: gods, philosophy, brahma-sutras, body

I have heard it claimed on this site that the Brahma Sutras state that the devas have only causal and subtle bodies, and do not have gross bodies. What are the specific verses stating this?

Comment: Refer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/54206/647