# Are the Brahma Sutras saying that idols are the physical forms of the Gods?

Tags: gods, philosophy, rituals, brahma-sutras, idols

> If it be said that (the corporeal individuality of the gods involves) a contradiction to (sacrificial) works; we deny that, on account of the observation of the assumption (on the part of the gods) of several (forms).
>
> Brahma Sutras 1:3:27

Here, when it talks about the multiple bodies devas can assume, are these bodies the idols that humans build? Do the devas assume the idols as their physical forms?

Comment: @blue_ego Can you repeat?

Comment: And if this is true, can this also be extended to the 7 classical planets? Are they the physical forms assumed by the Gods with whom they share their names?

Comment: no they're not referring to the idols. Devas are kama-rupa. they can assume any form they want. the idols (or murtis as we hindus call them) are consecrated forms of devas according to agama shastras. just as a piece of paper becomes valued as a currency once the government undersigns it, a piece of stone becomes valued as a deva once vedic shastras undersign it.

Comment: @mar If they can assume any form they want, doesn't that mean they can assume the idols as their forms?

Comment: they sure can. but the idols that are consecrated by humans are not necessarily inhabited by the devas.

Comment: @mar Why do the Brahma Sutras seem to say that the ability of the devas to assume multiple bodies is necessary for making sacrifices to them, if the devas do not necessarily inhabit idols?

Comment: what does multiple bodies have anything to do with idols ? they can inhibit them. they can also take multiple other bodies that look human or any other animal or shape or form.